# Panel scrollbar does not appear to be scrolled after setting scroll value

Tags: c#, winforms

WinForms app, c# - I'm having trouble making the vertical scroll bar appear to be scrolled after setting the scroll value programmatically on a panel (following the repopulation of controls in that panel). Example:
Form open:

```
void form_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.Controls.Clear();
    this.Size = new(250, 250);
    Panel panel = new() { AutoScroll = true, Size = new(200, 200), BorderStyle = BorderStyle.FixedSingle, Location = new(5, 5) };
    this.Controls.Add(panel);
    this.Click += this_Click;
}
```

result:

[image: Basic form with just a panel]

Now, the click handler, I just want to clear what's in the panel and refill it with controls to demonstrate what I'm doing in the larger context:

```
void this_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    foreach (Panel panel in Controls.OfType<Panel>())
    {
        Console.WriteLine(panel.VerticalScroll.Value.ToString() + "/" +
            panel.VerticalScroll.Maximum.ToString()); // prints "0/100"
        panel.Controls.Clear();
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        {
            Label label = new() {
                AutoSize = false,
                Size = new(175, 100),
                Location = new(5, i * 105),
                BorderStyle = BorderStyle.FixedSingle,
                Text = i.ToString()
            };
            panel.Controls.Add(label);
        }
        panel.VerticalScroll.Value = 200;
        Console.WriteLine(panel.VerticalScroll.Value.ToString() + "/" +
            panel.VerticalScroll.Maximum.ToString()); // prints "0/519"
    }
}
```

The result you see is that the panel is scrolled, but the scroll bar appears to be sitting at the top position:

[image: labels added to panel, panel scrolled but scroll bar shows top position]

Jogging the scroll bar manually after this puts it in the right place:

[image: Same as previous except scroll bar appears in correct position]

How to I make the scroll bar appear to be scrolled to where it actually is after setting the value?

Comment: This `panel.Controls.Clear();` is not right. You must dispose of the controls since you are creating new ones in the inner loop. Also, call `SuspendLayout();` before the outer loop and `ResumeLayout();` after it. Pass `true` to the latter if needed which calls the `PerformLayout();` method internally.

Comment: Also 2, Consider using the [FlowLayoutPanel](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.flowlayoutpanel?view=windowsdesktop-7.0) as the parent and container of the other panels.

Comment: Great insight, thanks! I haven't messed around with FlowLayoutPanels before, but after a brief look, they appear to be very useful and I'll be checking those out further soon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On advice from @dr.null above, I've amended the click event which has resolved the issue:

```
void this_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    foreach (Panel panel in Controls.OfType<Panel>())
    {
        panel.SuspendLayout(); // addition
        for (int i = panel.Controls.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--)
        { panel.Controls[i].Dispose(); } // replace Clear call
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        {
            Label label = new() {
                AutoSize = false,
                Size = new(175, 100),
                Location = new(5, i * 105),
                BorderStyle = BorderStyle.FixedSingle,
                Text = i.ToString()
            };
            panel.Controls.Add(label);
        }
        panel.VerticalScroll.Value = 200;
        panel.ResumeLayout(true); // addition, calls PerformLayout
    }
}
```